# Deep model nesting in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested

In quite a big project I encountered a problem of deep model nesting. For example there exists a model like this:

```
class Communication::Conversation::ForProposal < Communication::Conversation::Base
  ...
end
```

and furthermore every time we need to specify table_name, class_name, foreign_keys and so on.

What alternatives do you know and how actually in your opinion models should be named?

Comment: @Beerlington at all? Sometimes it makes sense. E.g., if you have some subsystem in the project that consists of several models working together.

Comment: I had a dialog with my friends so we concluded that nesting is cool for STI models and for controllers, to separate Admin:: and users parts. Anything else?

Comment: I've never had luck with it and DHH recommended against it so I took his word for it.

Comment: @Beerlington, could you please post DHH's article as the answer?

Comment: I think I can see DHH's point.  Rails keeps things DRY where other frameworks' primitives have to specify table_name, class_name, foreign_keys.  In Rails, if you follow naming conventions, these don't have to be passed as arguments.  When models are in a namespace DHH cannot make Rails guess right, so you lose the benefit and do have to specify all these things.

Comment: @makaroni4 I can't find the original quote, but if you google "DHH namespaced models" you'll find a bunch of blogs referencing it (http://m.onkey.org/namespaced-models). A lot has changed in Rails core since he made the statement and I when tried using them so maybe things are better now.

Comment: @Beerlington, thanks a lot) I wish your models to be always neat :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using mixins. It helps you organize your code by functionalities, which lead you to a cleaner code. The following page explains it well.

http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/

I have been looking at some source code for Rails on GitHub, and it is very clean. They heavily utilize mixins.

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel/lib

Comment: Using mixins doesn't group the models together.  I have additional connections to other databases, (although this is a transitional measure), and some of the databases have the same table names, so namespacing also diffuses name collisions, for which mixins are no help.

Comment: I see in the documentation of the REXML utility an example of doing an include REXML and then not having to qualify the namespace.  http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/docs/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of rails you can namespace your models by putting them in a directory under app/models. You might try app/models/communication/conversation for those models.

Comment: That doesn't address the issue of having to specify the namespace when using the models.

Comment: I'm not clear on where you do and don't want to specify the namespaces. If it's when writing each of them and talking about the others, then you could wrap things in a module for clarity. That should make any references to classes within the module not require the prefix.  If you're trying to reduce the need for specifying the namespace outside the module, then you need something like `include ModuleName`, but I think that will load the entire module into the current class.